Functional equation $f\left(xf\left(y\right)+f\left(f\left(y\right)\right)\right)=\left(x+1\right)f\left(y\right)$
I have reviewed my note in British MO China Camp and one line of my note didn't make sense. It has been a while so I really forget how can I solve this functional equation. Please help.

Problem: Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\left(xf\left(y\right)+f\left(f\left(y\right)\right)\right)=\left(x+1\right)f\left(y\right)$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
My note suggested to let $x=0$ and get $f\left(f\left(f\left(y\right)\right)\right)=f\left(y\right)$ which implies $f$ is surjective.
I really couldn't get why.

Also, if possible, I'd also like to know the source of this problem.

Any constant function $f \equiv c$ satisfies $f = f^{\circ 3}$, so the argument would have to rely on another property of the solution of your equation. Surjectivity will rather come from taking a $y$ such that $f(y) \neq 0$, and then making $x$ run through the reals.

If $f$ is not the zero fucntion then choose $y$ with $f(y)\neq 0$ and surjectivity becomes obvious.

The constant function $0$ satisfies the original functional equation so you can't hope to prove that $f$ is surjective.  You must have missed some other assumption, like that $f$ assumes at least one nonzero value.

With $x=0$ you get that $f$ is an involution and in particular a bijection when restricted to its image. While all constant functions satisfy $f=f^{\circ 3}$ the zero function is the only constant function that satisfies the original equation.

I'm curious: are there any functional equations with triply-nested functions and nontrivial solutions?

@BenjaminWang These FE exist. For example, $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ is a non-trivial function that satisfies $f^{\circ 3}=\text{Id}$. You can create a FE base on this function.

Notice that $f\equiv 0$ is a solution, so it need not be bijective. Suppose we have another solution with $f\not\equiv0$ and let $x_0$ be such that $f(x_0)\neq0$. Then, plugging $y=x_0$ we get
$$f(xf(x_0)+f(f(x_0)))=(x+1)f(x_0)$$
therefore, $f$ is surjective, since for every $y\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$f\left(\left(\frac y{f(x_0)}-1\right)f(x_0)+f(f(x_0))\right)=y$$
Now, for every $t$ in $\mathbb R$ we can choose a preimage and plug it on $y$, so we get that for every $t$
$$f(xt+f(t))=(x+1)t$$
now, let $t=1$ and $x=w-f(1)$ and we get
$$f(w)=w-f(1)+1$$
So in particular $f$ must be of the form
$$f(x)=x+a$$
plugging this in the functional equation we get
$$xt+t+2a=(x+1)t\implies a=0$$
so the only solutions are $f\equiv 0$ and $f=\text{Id}$

First note that the zero function is a solution. Let now $f$ be another solution. Then, $(x+1)f(y)$ can take any real value hence $f$ is surjective, so that the functional equation is equivalent to
$$\forall x,t\quad f\left(xt+f\left(t\right)\right)=xt+t$$
which is the same as
$$f(f(0))=0\text{ and }\forall t\ne0,\forall s\quad f\left(s+f\left(t\right)\right)=s+t$$
or equivalently
$$f(f(0))=0\text{ and }\forall t\ne0,\forall u\quad f\left(u\right)-u=-\left(f(t)-t\right)$$
i.e.
$$\forall u\quad f\left(u\right)=u.$$
